# How do I get how many exams have been done

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 3 collections: Categories, Exams and Results.

For each Category I have some exams. If one exam is done, I add its result on "Result" collection.

I have take all exams for each category.
The problem is that I can't count how many of them are done.

This is what I get right now:

```
{ category: "Test", total_exams: 10 }
```

This is what I want:

```
{ category: "Test", total_exams: 10, done_exam: 4 }
```

Below you can see what I have done until now:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/upSAPkYe4DR

Comment: Your question is quite not clear.

Comment: I edited my question, hope it's more clear now

Comment: Is this an exercise? Having 3 collections looks like a poor design to me. Should be one or max 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fixes:

- second `$lookup` stage, let to pass `examsCount._id`,
- inside pipeline `$match` stage match expression, `$exam_id with $$examId`
- put `user_id` match condition outside expression
- `$count` total documents in `count`
- $addFields`to get`doneExams.count`this will return count in zero index, get it using`$first`or`$arrayElemAt`

```
db.categories.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "exams",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "categoryId",
      as: "examsCount"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "results",
      let: { examId: "$examsCount._id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [{ $in: ["$exam_id", "$$examId"] }]
            },
            user_id: 22222222
          }
        },
        { $count: "count" }
      ],
      as: "doneExams"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      examsCount: { $size: "$examsCount" },
      doneExams: { $first: "$doneExams.count" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dn6QeauPyP2)

> There are many approaches to get this result, i have just resolved your issue in your approach.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This isn't the best solution ?

Comment: depends on your schema, data in collection and declared index on fields.